# Get width of a 2D GameObject in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm trying to get the width and height of a 2D GameObject.
My GameObject is simply a prefab created using sprite.

I have tried solutions from other posts but they don't work for me:

```
Vector2 size = myGameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().bounds.size;
float width = size.x;
float height = size.y;
```

and

```
Vector2 size = myGameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.size;
float width = size.x;
float height = size.y;
```

My prefab has a `Circle Collider 2D` but `x` and `y` always returns `0`

I'm using Unity 5.5.0f3, not sure if previous solutions apply to this version.

Comment: have you tried receiving the collider as an actual `CircleCollider2D`, and accessing its `radius` variable? Circle geometry typically commits a height and a width, as the x and y values are always the same, I.e. its radius. Alternatively, `BoxCollider2D` should contain actual values for both `width` and `height`.

Comment: Try GetComponent<Transform>().lossyScale.x for width and GetComponent<Transform>().lossyScale.y for height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use [CircleCollider2D.radius](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CircleCollider2D-radius.html)

So get the radius and multiply it by 2.

```
var size = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius;
Debug.Log(2 * size);
```